# Delete Specific Duplicate Data with Condition

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which contains some duplicated data and I want to delete specific entries from it based on the value stored in the Time column.

In my table, ID: 504289 has 3 entries:

```
Date       Time              Place  ID
20161128   2016-11-30 12:54  East   504289
20161128   2016-11-30 12:55  East   504289
20161128   2016-11-30 13:10  East   504289
```

I want to delete only the entries where the time interval between it and previous entries have a difference of 15 minutes or less.

Applied to the table above, only the 12:55 record will be removed because 1254 is the first record and 13:10 is greater than 15 minutes from it.

Can anyone help figure out the query?

Comment: Please tag your question with the database you are using.  Also, what is the data type of the `time` column.

Comment: time column is varchar

Answer (score 2):

Using standard SQL, you can delete a records that are within 15 minutes of another record.  Assuming your `time` column is some sort of date/time type for the database you are using, the SQL would look something like this:

```
delete from t
    where exists (select 1
                  from t t2
                  where t2.date = t.date and
                        t2.time < t.time and
                        t2.time > t.time - interval '15 minute'
                 );
```

Date/time arithmetic varies significantly among databases.  The above is a general form that gives the shape of the query.

Comment: Imagine that a table has 30 rows with timestamps one minute apart from each other. From, say, `12:00` till `12:29`. If I understood your query correctly, it will delete 29 rows - all except the last one. It doesn't look like what OP wants. To start with, he wants to keep the first row, not the last.